# Cosa significa "appassuliato"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Per questo Moe Rosen preferiva Dagoland. Qui nessuno lo puniva se si metteva a dipingere galline, conigli e bambini sui muri dei cortili e sulle tavole dei depositi di carbone. I dago lo trovavano solo matto. Ridevano delle strane immagini che si lasciava dietro – ma non le cancellavano. Dipingeva gli animali sofferenti, coi becchi socchiusi e gli occhi sbarrati; perfino ai fiori **appassuliati** e agonizzanti restituiva una disperata bellezza.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "appassuliato"? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo di uso regionale, possibilmente derivato dal napoletano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo [dizionario di dialetto napoletano](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf) si trova la seguente spiegazione:

> **appassuliato**-a: agg. e part. di appassuliarse: appassito,
>   sfiorito, stanco (vezz. appassuliatiéllo-èlla).

Il termine significa quindi appassito, riferito nello specifico ai fiori.

Answer (score -2):

Il termine fu coniato da Gabriele D'Annunzio per la famosa canzone napoletana 'A Vucchella ( la boccuccia).

Comment: Fonte? Dall'altra risposta parrebbe un normale termine del dialetto napoletano.